# Codeigniter Multilanguage / Sessions not refering properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I have again a question in the CodeIgniter enviroment. When i use session to determine the language of the page i get errors if i reenter the page after a certain time. These are the settings of the session.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
```

The proplem exactly is the difference between the session handling. The langauges are getting mixed on the entire page. If i use this code:

```
{% if (session_get('language_id')==1) %}
            {{home_page_content.box_one_title_in_english}}
          {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==2) %}
            {{home_page_content.box_one_title_in_french}}
          {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==3) %}
            {{home_page_content.box_one_title_in_german}}
          {% elseif (session_get('language_id')==4) %}
            {{home_page_content.box_one_title_in_spanish}}
          {% else %}
            {{home_page_content.box_one_title_in_english}}
          {% endif  %}
```

i get the english because of no session at all. but in the same time language files reached trough this strings:

```
{{language_key('example')}}
```

the language is set to the one i previously set while being on the page. so i have in my case english text and german links. I figured it is do to some issues with the session saved in the cookies since i clear my browser i get the whole page in english and i am then able to set the language which will stay for some time. but even if i set a expiration of the session the issue is still there and id like to be able to give the user the experience of setting his personal language. I hope my question is understandable :) here some more code which might be useful:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('dbal', 'session', 'auth', 'twig','email','form_validation','database');
```

and the function

```
function set_language($language_id)
{   
    $query="SELECT * FROM languages WHERE id = ? "; 
    $languages_array = $this->db->fetchAssoc($query,array($language_id));
    if(!empty($languages_array)){
        setcookie('language_cookie', $languages_array['language'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
        setcookie('language_id_cookie', $language_id, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
        $this->session->remove('language_id');
        $this->session->set('language_id',$language_id);
    }       
    else {
        $this->session->set('language_id',$language_id);
    }
}
```

thank you for your time! regards

Comment: Try to isolate the problem. Start from putting language id only inside session, see what will happen. Notice, that if you use basic session library settings, you use cookies - so it seems, you use cookies twice.

Comment: hey how do i put the language id only inside a session i dont quite understand how you mean. So you say that i dont need to set a cookie in the language function?

Comment: I think its duplication, simple example of language switching is in userguide - https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#example-of-switching-languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the problem could be achieved trought this instruction:

[Replace cookie helper set_cookie() with an improved version](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/commit/128d7194ca90ebc005c523f2918194af4ea924ed)

due to the comment of cssBlaster21895 i was able to adress the problem properly and so i could figure out that it sent multiple Set-Cookie headers. Thanks for the help!